# Ansible lineinfile command error when not using "tasks:" before the lineinfile items

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm with a problem when running lineinfile command. I've written the following script, which works like a charm:

```
- hosts: centos1
  user: root
  tasks:
  - name: Replace nsswitch.conf passwd configuration
    lineinfile:
          path: /etc/nsswitch.conf
          regexp: "^passwd:" #line to be searched
          line: "passwd:     xxx yyy zzz" # new line replacing the above
          state: present
          create: True 
    when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version|int >= 8
```

but on the prod server, yml scripts are summoned by a "main.yml", more or less like this:

```
---
include: script1.yml
include: script2.yml
include: myscript.yml
...
```

and then I was requested by my senior analyst to remove the "hosts", "user" and "tasks" from the final version, and add a tag on each lineinfile entry, which looked like this:

```
- name: Replace nsswitch.conf passwd configuration
  lineinfile:
        path: /etc/nsswitch.conf
        regexp: "^passwd:" #line to be searched
        line: "passwd:     files sss systemd" # new line replacing the above
        state: present
        create: True 
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version|int >= 8
  tags:
    - nsswwitch_change
```

but now when I run the playbook, either through my yml file or the main file, I get the following error:

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.27
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug 13 2020, 02:51:10) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /tmp/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /tmp/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /tmp/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /tmp/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
ERROR! 'lineinfile' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '/app/ansible/roles/linux-sap-hana/tasks/raul-mnsswitch.yml': line 26, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Replace nsswitch.conf passwd configuration
  ^ here
```

I'm literally out of ideas, because the only way I was able to make it work was adding the host, user and tasks at the beggining  of the playbook.

Any help would be appreciated folks, thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you top-level playbook looks like this:

```
include: script1.yml
include: script2.yml
include: myscript.yml
```

Then each of those included documents needs to be a playbook: that means it needs to be a list of plays, not a list of tasks:

```
- name: play 1
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    ...

- name: play 2
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    ...
```

Otherwise, how will Ansible know which hosts to target?

Note that the `include` module is [deprecated](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_module.html):

> #### DEPRECATED
>
> **Removed in**
>
> version 2.16
>
> **Why**
>
> it has too many conflicting behaviours depending on keyword combinations and it was unclear how it should behave in each case. new actions were developed that were specific about each case and related behaviours.
>
> **Alternative**
>
> include_tasks, import_tasks, import_playbook

You should be using `import_playbook` instead.

---

If you want to include a list of tasks, you can only do that via the [`include_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html) or [`import_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_tasks_module.html) modules, as part of task in a play:

```
- name: play 1
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: import script1
      import_tasks: script1.yml

    - name: import script2
      import_tasks: script2.yml
```

---

NB: To make sure you're clear on the nomenclature:

```
# This entire block is a playbook

# This is a play
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    # This is a task
    - name: Example task 1
      debug:
        msg: This is an example task

# This is a play
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    # This is a task
    - name: Example task 2
      debug:
        msg: This is an example task
```

Comment: @rsantos: as a complement to the above excellent answer, I encourage you to read [Ansible playbook keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html)